# Revert to multiple-display window setting from OSX Mavericks to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, osx-spaces, osx-mavericks

Updated to Mavericks..

Is there a way to set it back so that if a window goes off past the monitor, it will show the rest on another. Now it just cuts off the window and will only show on one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Open **System Preferences**, go to **Mission Control**, find **Displays have separate spaces** and uncheck it (you'll have to logout and login to make the change effective).  This pretty much restores multiple-display behavior to what it was before Mavericks with just a single menubar, Dock, etc.

Comment: This solves the problem, but it affects other features and makes it even less usable.